# Replacing null values with np.nan

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, nan

I have a dataframe which has NaN values which when I assess with my code turn out to be 'null' values and are not np.nan values. Is there some code where I can replace these 'null NaN' values with np.nan?

```
df_select = df_select[['RoundDown','RoundUp']]
df_select

nullrows = df_select.isnull()
nullrows
```

[image]

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: what you mean ? null value from you pic , sames like it just work fine

Comment: I want those values for which the null is True to be np.nan values.

Comment: When I check for them to be = to np.nan values , it shows up as False

Comment: Post code NOT pictures with code.

Comment: Will do this immediately

Comment: `NaN != NaN`. That's why your comparison fails.

Comment: Right! Got it. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data frame is just construct well , when you try `.isnull` if it is true mean that cell is `np.nan` but also need to point it out

```
np.nan==np.nan
Out[178]: False
```